# Why tensor.view() is not working in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have the following piece of code.

```
embedded = self.embedding(input).view(1, 1, -1)
embedded = self.drop(embedded)
print(embedded[0].size(), hidden[0].size())
concatenated_output = torch.cat((embedded[0], hidden[0]), 1)
```

The last line of the code is giving me the following error.

> RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor sizes at /data/users/soumith/miniconda2/conda-bld/pytorch-0.1.9_1487344852722/work/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu:141

Please note, when I am printing the tensor shapes at line no. 3, I am getting the following output.

```
torch.size([1, 300]) torch.size([1, 1, 300])
```

Why I am getting `[1, 300]` shape for `embedded` tensor even though I have used the view method as `view(1, 1, -1)`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `What is self.drop??` Can you print the embedded size before you call the `self.drop` function?

Comment: embedded size is same. self.drop is a dropout layer.

Comment: Then in that case `print(embedded.size())` will give you `[1, 1, 300]`. Since you are printing `print(embedeed[0].size)` this will be `[1, 300]`. Given those shape you wouldn't be able to perform the torch.cat operation. You need to have the same size along the dimension that you want to concatenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`embedded` was a 3d-tensor and `hidden` was a tuple of two elements (hidden states and cell states) where each element is a 3d-tensor. `hidden` was the output from LSTM layer. In PyTorch, LSTM returns hidden states [h] and cell states [c] as a tuple which made me confused about the error.

So, I updated the last line of the code as follows and it solved the problem.

```
concatenated_output = torch.cat((embedded, hidden[0]), 1)
```